# How can I configure the buttons on my Logitech Marble Mouse in Ubuntu (Karmic)?

Tags: ubuntu, logitech-mouse

By default the 2 small buttons on the insides of the right/left large buttons work as back and forward, I'd like to be able to change their behavior to something else (typically I like them to be up and down keys). I haven't installed any drivers for the mouse.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to get drivers from the manufacture. Did you check with logitech to see if they exist? (Outside of this, I'm not sure).

Comment: I haven't checked yet, but I will.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [GPointing Device Settings](http://live.gnome.org/GPointingDeviceSettings), a GUI tool for configuring button, scrolling and wheel emulation. You can install it via `sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings` (tested in Ubuntu 10.04).